# JavaScript causing all sub-menus to be one link instead of individual links on mobile (bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code with a working demo is located at:

https://jsfiddle.net/h744n4ek/

My issue is that on mobile (which can be recreated by resizing the jsfiddle result window), if you expand one of the li's with a submenu, the entire submenu block is treated as a link to the next li.

To clarify:

```
  <li><a href='#'>SUPPORT</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>sub1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>sub2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>sub3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='products.html'>PRODUCTS</a>
```

On mobile, Support's sub1, sub2, and sub3 are treated as a single block with a href to products.html.

I'm quite new to JavaScript and am having issues identifying why this is happening. Could anyone point out where my JS code is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li {
float: none;
}
```

Removing **float: none;** will fix it.

Comment: THANK YOU. I thought I was going crazy, I guess that's what happens when you're staring at a problem too long without a break. Thank you so much.